# Getting IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting `IndexError: tuple index out of range` in following code at line 3 `if params` :

```
   def query(self, sql, params=None):
        #params in form of a tuple
        if params:
            sql_new=sql.format(params)
            print sql_new
            self.cursor.execute(sql_new)
        else : self.cursor.execute(sql)
        return self.cursor.fetchall()
```

I am trying to check if the 2nd parameter has been passed to the query or not, if it has been passed then format the sql, `sql="select * from {} where fl_id='{}'"` and `params=("a","b")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is add `*` to your formatting statement:

```
sql.format(*params)
```

This way you provide an unpacked tuple to the `format`.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your code into something like this:

```
    #params in form of a tuple
    if params and len(params) == 2 :
```

This way you can be sure that you have exactly 2 parameters.

Then you have to pass the tuple elements separately as:

```
        sql_new=sql.format(params[0], params[1])
```

because `.format()` expects two parameters and gets only one, hence the error you get.